# delete file in pentaho

Tags: regex, pentaho, delete-file

I need to delete some ".text" files but I can not delete all files with this extension. wanted to use regular expressions to search by filename. can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several steps you can use to achieve that. Easiest one is the Job Step Delete Files. You can specify multiple folders and RegExp for each individual folder.

RegExp ignoring numbers - hs_err_pid.*\.txt

Meaning, it will match any file that begins with hs_err_pid and ends in .txt ... having any amount of characters between hs_err_pid and .txt

Comment: Thank you
but I'd like to know what formula I use in RegEx? The file name I want to delete is: hs_err_pidxxxx.
NOTE: "xxxx" are numbers, which always change

Comment: Do you need to account for those numbers ? Or they don't matter ? If the numbers dont matter you can ignore them completely. I Edited my answer with a possible RegExp.

Comment: thank you very much! I succeeded in deleting the files